# Form won't display. . . Dooh!

Tags: java-me

I could use a little help.  I got this program to work right then I found out I had to use the MVC design.  It seems pretty simple but, my little toy program won't display my forms.  HELP!!  See the below snipets:

PART OF MIDLET

```
  public MileageMidlet()
  {

        // First get a blank user form
        form = new Form("Bradford Gas Mileage Calculator");

        startPage = new StartPageView();
        inputScreen = new InputScreen();
        calculateMileage = new CalculateMileage();

        startCmd = new Command ("Start",Command.SCREEN,5);
        clearCmd = new Command ("Clear",Command.SCREEN,1);
        enterCmd = new Command ("Enter",Command.SCREEN,1);
        exitCmd = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);

        // Set up event handlers to process user commands
        form.setCommandListener(this);
  }


  public void startApp() {

        startPage.createView(form);            

        form.addCommand(startCmd);
        form.addCommand(exitCmd);

        // Display initial form
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(form);
 }
```

START PAGE VIEW CLASS

```
 import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

 public class StartPageView
 {

 StringItem strgItm, strgItm2;
 private Command startCmd, exitCmd;

 public StartPageView()
 {

 }

 public void createView(Form form)
 {
        // First get a blank user form
        form.deleteAll();
        form = new Form("Bradford Gas Mileage Calculator");
        strgItm = new StringItem ("","Welcome to the Bradford Mobile Gas Mileage Calculator!");
        strgItm2 = new StringItem ("","To obtain you gas mileage please click the start button.");            
        form.append(strgItm);
        form.append(strgItm2);

 }
```

I got nothing! Really literally a blue screen.

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with MIDP or J2ME. The problem is of the semantics of how arguments are passed to methods.

It;s important to remember that arguments to method are ***passed by value in Java***. The consequence is that when an object that is passed to a method, a copy of that reference is passed. Any changes to the reference of the object in the method does not have any affect outside of it.

Please see [this](http://academic.regis.edu/dbahr/GeneralPages/IntroToProgramming/JavaPassByValue.htm) article for more information.

So in your code,

```
form.deleteAll();
form = new Form("Bradford Gas Mileage Calculator");
```

Comment the above two lines. Everything should be fine.